# Array.Find is not working as expected

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Help me out here, I must be doing something wrong,

The first example here works fine

```
 DatabaseType = Array.Find(pArgs, Function(s As String) s.ToLower.Contains("/db:")).Replace("/db:", "")
```

but if that was false and my variable turned out to be nothing then it throws and object ref exception, so as a result I wrapped an IF around it, but then it never returns true, and also it doesnt populate the variable, like the one below:

```
 If DatabaseType = Array.Find(pArgs, Function(s As String) s.ToLower.Contains("/db:")).Replace("/db:", "") Then LogAndTrace("Database Type", DatabaseType)
```

What I need to do is :

Basically I have a num of commandlines arguments I am getting and I need to distiguish what they are each according to their prefix and assign them to the right property , but they are not always going to be there so I wanted to first see if it exist then replace the prefix with nothing, assign it to the property and write it to the log.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here without more information. Please post a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. It's not clear whether you're expecting the `If` statement to be performing a comparison or an assignment...

Comment: @JonSkeet , Basically I have a numch of commandlines arguments I am etting and I need to distiguish what they are each according to their prefix and assign them to the right property , but they are not always going to be there so I wanted to first see if it exist then replace the prefix with nothing, assign it to the property and write it to the log.

Comment: If sounds like you should be assigning a value to a local variable *then* checking if it's Nothing, *then* performing the replace and log...

Comment: @JonSkeet ok, but what if the value is not there , it just throws an error, is there a way that I can do the check to see if teh value exist before assigining it ??

Comment: It throws an exception because you're calling `Replace` *unconditionally*. See my answer.

Comment: (Additionally, it's worth looking through your question - it's *very* confused, particularly the title, given that `Array.Find` on an array of strings doesn't return a Boolean value at all...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to try to perform assignment within the *condition* of an `If` statement. 
I suspect you want something like this:

```
Dim databaseType = Array.Find(pArgs, Function(s As String) s.ToLower.Contains("/db:"))
If databaseType IsNot Nothing Then
    databaseType = databaseType.Replace("/db:", "")
    LogAndTrace("Database Type", databaseType)
End If
```

(That's using a local variable... if you want to assign a *property*, I'd do that within the `If` block, when you've performed the replacement.)